# How can I inject with dagger into my Application before it's created, from functional tests on Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, functional-testing, dagger

Our Application subclass currently holds most of our singletons (REST adapter, HTTP client, caches etc...). I've modified it so that these get injected via dagger 1, with the hope that I could replace them with mocked versions when running functional tests.

I have tried these approaches:

- Have a static variable to an optional test module, that is normally null but gets set from tests. But I haven't found a place where I could run code to set that static variable to my test module in my functional tests (with either ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or the new ActivityTestRule). The Application is created before any of my test code runs.
- Define the list of modules to use in a class that gets overridden entirely in the test code, as suggested by Jake Wharton in [example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020). But this doesn't seem to work for tests, which seem to include all the classes from the debug variant and all the classes from the androidTest variant, resulting in a conflict. Also it would mean that all my tests get the mocked versions, which might not be ideal.

Is there a better way to inject dependencies from test modules in the Application class, when running functional activity tests?

Comment: When overriding the modules, are you using `@Module(overrides = true)`? Can you share some code for the second version?

Comment: @Emmanuel yes I use overrides = true. By conflict I mean that dex finds that there are 2 classes with the same path and bails out (src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/Modules.java and src/androidTest/java/com/mycompany/myapp/Modules.java